# How to request.getresponse() with cookie

Tags: c#, webrequest

I want add Cookies and get http website source 
how to add Cookies to my code and when getresponse() the website read my Cookies ?

```
enter code here
WebRequest scienceRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");       
WebResponse scienceResponse = scienceRequest.GetResponse();
Stream ReceiveStream = scienceResponse.GetResponseStream();
scienceResponse = scienceRequest.GetResponse();
ReceiveStream = scienceResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);
string strResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();
readStream.Close();
scienceResponse.Close();
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking here...  What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920298%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?ppud=4):

```
private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
        request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isf =
        IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForSite())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile("CookieExCookies",
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(isfs))
            {
                foreach (Cookie cookieValue in response.Cookies)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Cookie: " + cookieValue.ToString());
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CookieContainer` for this. You can create that using

```
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
// Optionally add some values to the container
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.domain.com"), new Cookie("name", "Raeled"));
```

You can then attach the container to your request (you can do this again and again to keep using the same cookies):

```
(scienceRequest as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookieJar;
```

The webpage will then use the cookies in the container and also change them if needed.
If the webpage changed them you can read them back using the following:

```
CookieCollection collection = cookieJar.GetCookies(new Uri("http://www.domain.com"));
string myValue = collection["name"].Value;
```

to get or set you need to provide the URI because the CookieContainer can keep track of cookies for differend domains in a single `CookieContainer`.